# Get a list within a list using Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I need to return a list within a list using linq(lambda), however, still not getting required syntax.

I have a list of WikiMeta which I want to query and return all the WikiGroups as a new list.

Note: Some properties have been removed from clarity.

```
List<WikiMeta> Meta;

public class WikiMeta
{
    public List<WikiGroup> Groups = new List<WikiGroup>();
}

public class WikiGroup
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Question is unclear. Are you trying to filter a `List<T>` ? You can use `Where`

Comment: you might be looking for `SelectMany`, like: `Meta.SelectMany(m => m.Groups);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get them all as a flat list using `SelectMany`:

```
var groups = meta.SelectMany(m => m.Groups).ToList();
```

This will give you a `List<WikiGroup>`.

[Documentation for `SelectMany`.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336.aspx)

You can perform any query you wish on the main `List<WikiMeta>` as such:

```
var filteredGroups = meta
    .Where(m => m.IsActive) // Fictional "IsActive" boolean property.
    .SelectMany(m => m.Groups)
    .ToList();
```

Using this fluent-style functional approach to querying collections, you can start to build up more complicated queries.

If you wish to leave the query deferred until it is iterated, remove `ToList`, which will give you an `IEnumerable<WikiGroup>`.